# How to check if named capture group exists?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm wondering what is the proper way to test if a named capture group exists. Specifically, I have a function that takes a compiled regex as an argument. The regex may or may not have a specific named group, and the named group may or may not be present in a string being passed in:

```
some_regex = re.compile("^foo(?P<idx>[0-9]*)?$")
other_regex = re.compile("^bar$")

def some_func(regex, string):
    m = regex.match(regex, string)
    if m.group("idx"):     # get *** IndexError: no such group here...
        print(f"index found and is {m.group('idx')}")
    print(f"no index found")

some_func(other_regex, "bar")
```

I'd like to test if the group exists without using `try` -- as this would short circuit the rest of the function, which I would still need to run if the named group was not found.

Comment: why would `try/except` "short circuit the rest of the function"?

Comment: It is here [How to get group name of match regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856238/how-to-get-group-name-of-match-regular-expression-in-python)

Comment: I suppose I could do a local `try`/`except` -- sorry new to python, so I always imagine a `try` around a whole block of code rather than around one or two lines...

Comment: I added both scenarios where a named capturing group is checked for to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [`groupdict` of the `match` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict):

```
import re
some_regex = re.compile("^foo(?P<idx>[0-9]*)?$")

match = some_regex.match('foo11')
print(True) if match and 'idx' in match.groupdict() else print(False) # True
match = some_regex.match('bar11')
print(True) if match and 'idx' in match.groupdict() else print(False) # False
```

Answer (score 10):

**If you want to check if a *match data object* contains a named group capture**, i.e. if a named group matched, you can use the [`MatchData#groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict) property:

```py
import re
some_regex = re.compile("^foo(?P<idx>[0-9]*)?$")

match = some_regex.match('foo11')
print(match and 'idx' in match.groupdict()) # => True

match = some_regex.match('bar11')
print(match and 'idx' in match.groupdict()) # => None (coerceable to False)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/W3eZ6s). Note that if you need a boolean output, simply wrap the expression inside `print` with `bool(...)`: `print(bool(match and 'idx' in match.groupdict()))`.

**If you need to check if a group with a specific name exists in the compile pattern**, you can use [`Pattern.groupindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.groupindex) to check if the group name exists:

```py
def some_func(regex, group_name):
   return group_name in regex.groupindex
```

The documentation says:

> **`Pattern.groupindex`**
> A dictionary mapping any symbolic group names defined by `(?P<id>)` to group numbers. The dictionary is empty if no symbolic groups were used in the pattern.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Fkriro):

```py
import re
some_regex = re.compile("^foo(?P<idx>[0-9]*)?$")
other_regex = re.compile("^bar$")

def some_func(regex, group_name):
   return group_name in regex.groupindex

print(some_func(some_regex,"bar"))  # => False
print(some_func(some_regex,"idx"))  # => True
print(some_func(other_regex,"bar")) # => False
print(some_func(other_regex,"idx")) # => False
```